# Select when in a loop, select single, shows multiple selected

Tags: ember.js

When Ember.select is used in a {{#each}}, if I select option in one select, it shows as if it is selected in all the other selects. Below is the code and screen shots.

Code in template :

{{#each feed in model.feeddefinitions}}

```
                {{#if isEditing}}
                    <td> {{view Ember.Select
                    content=model.sections
                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    prompt="Select Section"
                    value=selectedSection}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" {{action 'add_section_to_feed' model feed.id}}>Add</button>
                    </td>
                {{/if}}
            </tr>

        {{/each}}
```

Comment: put the code in ember js bin and I will help you out.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/celefokoxi/1/edit I tried to add code as much I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing this issue because selectedSection's context is not an individual feed.

If every feed has a 'selectedSection' attribute, you can give 'value=feed.selectedSection'

Or else, you have to define an itemController for an individual feed and define the selectedSection property in it.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to how to define an itemController for an individual feed ?

Comment: I tried feed.selectedSection, it fixes the visual stuff but at controller I don't get the value. How should I access the value.

Comment: @plzdontkillme model.feeddefinitions will have the correct data. i.e. Each feed will have a selectedSection attribute which will hold the corresponding selected value

Comment: I am giving 50 points to user2601763 as using his solution of assigning value=feed.selectedSection fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your `Ember.Select`s are sharing a single controller and all of them are bound to the same property in the same controller `value=selectedSection`.

What you need to do is have a separate controller for each `Ember.Select`. You need a new controller for each item, for this purpose you can use the `render` helper.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xahevi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

All of your selects are bound onto the same property.

You either need to bind the value/selection onto a model property or onto a controller property for each item.  You can have the `each` helper wrap each model in a controller as follows:

```
{{#each feed in model.feeddefinitions itemController='feed-definition'}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do is -

declare item controller as `{{#each itemController=DesignPhotoController}}` while looping.
so that each individual object will have a separate controller.

And add

```
 selectedSection: null,
```

in `DesignPhotoController` and access it via `this.get("selectedSection")` in the controller.

Here is the - [FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/vibohu/1/edit?html,js,output)